# nginx and httpd. (99: Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: nginx, networking, linux-networking, centos7, httpd

i have a dedicated not managed server and use centos7 as OS, after a reboot and a new secondary ssd on my server, the httpd and nginx services no longer start.

the ips configuration was not touched and has been working for two years, the additional ips were added in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

like
ifcfg-enInterface:0
ifcfg-enInterface:1
ifcfg-enInterface:2
ifcfg-enInterface:3

with the command `ifconfig` the extra interfaces not appears `enInterface:0...enInterface:3`, just the `enInterface, lo, docker,etc`, but no `enInterface:0...enInterface:3`

with the `ip addr show enInterface:0` command I get a response from the ip configuration, but appears the ip of the main interface `enInterface` not the ip of enInterface:0

I get the following errors when checking the status of the services:

```
systemctl status httpd
May 18 10:06:53 srv1.mydomain.com httpd[23715]: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address MYIP:8080

systemctl status nginx
May 18 10:06:53 srv1.mydomain.com nginx[23716]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to MYIP:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

i modify the `httpd.service` file to:

```
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

and the `nginx.service` to

```
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

but the httpd and nginx services still do not start.

i think the problem besides on the extra ips, but the config was not touched

any ideas to up the extras ips
enInterface:0,..., enInterface:3

thanks in advance

Comment: show the output of `lsof -i :8080`

Comment: @djdomi the output of that command is empty

Comment: then show the complete nginx and apache configuration included with the vhosts and by the way, fix the question, only one issue at a time, as you stated the Webservers seems not to start

Comment: by the way, since I read the question in a silent moment, there are multiple questions in here. so please update the question due a possible [x and y problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)

Comment: I basically have the same problem right now. After upgrade from Debian 11 to 12 nginx not starting after reboot. (network config was not touched I think, though)
I have to manually start nginx: `systemctl start nginx`, then it works. Any insight to this would really be apprieciated.